# Unable to create Derby database over the Network on Windows, Error 40000 / XJ041 / XBM02?

Tags: derby, javadb

I tried several variations on this documented example from [the tutorial here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html%20here)

```
ij version 10.10
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest;create=true';
ERROR XJ041: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'MyDbTest', see the
 next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM02
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:\temp\MyDbTest;create=true';
ERROR XJ041: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'c:\temp\MyDbTest',
 see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM02
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:/temp/MyDbTest;create=true';
ERROR XJ041: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'c:/temp/MyDbTest',
 see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM02
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/file://c:/temp/MyDbTest;create=true';
ERROR 08001: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/file://c:/temp/MyDbTest;create=true
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest;create=false';
ERROR 08004: The connection was refused because the database MyDbTest;create=false was not found.
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest;create=true';
ERROR XJ041: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'MyDbTest', see the
 next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM02
ij>
```

Comment: What's in the derby.log file for your Derby Network Server (the one that is running on localhost:1527)?

Comment: Mon Sep 14 07:07:56 CDT 2015 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.11.1.1 - (1616546) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527

Comment: Try setting ij.exceptionTrace to see if you get any more clues: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/tools/rtoolsijproprefexceptiontrace.html

Comment: I thinks you can get help from derby.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error before and it was because Db already exists.

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue arises when derby fails to write on to the disk. Restart command prompt using administrator. Hopefully, this issue will be resolved.